# php using brackets in if statments

Tags: php, brackets, strpos

i have a small problem.

I am grabbing content from a url and saving it to a variable which works great

But the content i am grabbing form times ends in (0)

i have tried using the code below to check if ( exists in the variable

```
    if (strpos($name,')') !== false) {
          // do function here
    }
```

but the problem is that php seems to be taking the ) as the closing tag for the ( before $name

Does anyone one know how i can fix this?

Comment: Please show us your **real** and **full** code! This code here won't produce any errors

Comment: that is the real and full code that is all you need the veriable simply contains "jon mole (0)" and i need to check is theveriable contains ) that bracket

Comment: Well this code works fine for me! Please post the exact error message you get! (Add error reporting: `<?php
  ini_set("display_errors", 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ?>`)

Answer (score 0):

it will work fine, your $name variable should contain (0) then the below code will echo found

```
$name="test string (0)";
if (strpos($name,')') !== false) {
    // do function here
    echo "found";
}
```

Comment: Well that doesn't fix the problem from OP! Just to say that it works? But for OP it doesn't work!, why?